# how do I change the stacking order or objects in XCode xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib

I know this is simple, but i cannot get one of my object behind the other. I looked for bring to Front, or some kind of index similar to z-index in CSS. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little bit hidden, but it is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378234/xcode-4-how-to-send-objects-in-nib-files-to-front-back) ;)