# Change layer of images

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

Is there a way to change the "layer" that `UIImageView` objects are drawn in? Whenever I add an image view to a view controller it defaults to drawing the most recently added one on top of all the others. So if I decide to add a "background" image it is now a "foreground" image and blocks everything else.

There isn't anything in the IB options or in the `UIImageView` class reference and I haven't been able to find anything here on SO. It's been a problem for a while and it's weird that I haven't seen anything about it before... I think it might just be my semantics coming from a delphi background.

Anyway, does anyone know about this issue / ICANHAZTEHCODEZ to fix it? Or is this just like the `UIScrollView` problem and poorly supported by the development environment.[image: Y U NO WORK]

This happens when I try to use the editor to arrange the subviews.

Comment: I don't run the blog anymore, talk to H2CO3 if you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bring a SubView to Front or Send it background programmatically using

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourImageView];
```

and

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:yourImageView];
```

when `self.view` must be the superview of your imageView

In IB, select a `UIControl` and from top menu bar select Editor->arrage->send to front or back

Comment: Thanks for the tip... for some reason my send options are grayed out. I might have to add the images to the header file and then call `bringSubviewToFront`.

Comment: You have to select the View in your IB first. Otherwise they appear greyed out.

Comment: Yeah, I selected it but when I looked up the help docs it says the new version of xcode does this randomly sometimes. Anyway, managed to fix it with your help and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378234/xcode-4-how-to-send-objects-in-nib-files-to-front-back

Comment: there is a simple work around. As you can see there is a list of all views on left side where your imageView is selected. You can always drag those controls up and down thus changing their z-index. Dragging up means moving back, dragging down means sending forward.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `UIView`'s `addSubview:` method, it will add it to the top of the view stack resulting in what you are seeing.

There are numerous other `UIView` methods you can use to determine the order of subviews. E.g.:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;

- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index;

- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;

- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
```