# Moving objects that are behind other objects in Storyboard

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I often stack objects in IB/Storyboard it's almost impossible to drag objects that are behind other objects without moving the objects in front. Is there anyway I can move the objects that are already selected but are behind other objects? It always selects the object that's at the top when I try to move it or do I have to bring it to the front and move it and then send it back to the back?

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: Yeah I always run into this issue. So far I have not seen any other solution other then bring it to the front to move it then putting it back.

Comment: boo. wish you could hold down like the control key and it would always drag the object that's selected... 
Another annoying issue is that if you have a TableView it will try to insert it into the TableViewCell rather than keeping it just ontop of the TableViewCell

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Control + Shift + Click on an object in Interface Builder to see a menu of all of the objects under the mouse.

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/934152/1374512

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I can select it, but can't move it.

Answer (score 8):

Still no enough reputations to add comment, so I have to make a comment as an answer.

As @nvrtd mentioned, you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then click to show controls selection popup.

but as @David said, in that way you can only select rather than drag/move using mouse:

> That doesn't work for me. I can select it, but can't move it.

my solution:

1. select the control first
2. move the control with keyboard arrow keys

Comment: this works! But what about when you need to RESIZE a view that is below another one?

Comment: @Rod no good solution yet. maybe you can uncheck the `installed` checkbox temporary for the front view before RESIZE your back view.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the order of the objects, depending on your design... might be a solution. See SO here.

[How to send objects in NIB files to front/back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378234/how-to-send-objects-in-nib-files-to-front-back)