# How to set the z-index of a Control in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

[image]

In general, there is no problem.

But there is a problem, as the screen shot.

I want to change the z index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4: How to send objects in NIB files to front/back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378234/xcode-4-how-to-send-objects-in-nib-files-to-front-back)